# Problema con tildes HTML utilizando UTF-8 enviado por PHPMailer

Tags: html

Estoy utilizando el charset UTF-8 de esta manera:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
```

Aunque con esto mi HTML se ve bien tanto abriéndolo en distintos navegadores como en gmail, no ocurre lo mismo en gestores como outlook o el gestor de correo de windows 10, donde no reconoce las tildes ni los caracteres especiales, pese a que he leído en internet que para solucionar este problema es UTF-8 el charset que se suele utilizar ¿Debo incluir algún otro charset?

Comment: Asegúrate de que el fichero se guarda con esa codificación, si pones UTF-8 pero luego lo guardas como ISO-8859 o similar, te pasará eso

Comment: Estoy utilizando sublime text y en las preferencias he añadido   "default_encoding": "UTF-8",
"fallback_encoding": "utf-8" para guardarlo como UTF-8 ¿Debo hacer algo más para asegurarme de que se guarda como UTF-8? (ya que usándolo de esta manera me sigue sin funcionar). También le he dado a "save with encoding" y he seleccionado UTF-8, pero se sigue sin mostrar bien.

Comment: tu pregunta es con respecto a HTML y la solucion que das es el PHPMailer, debes cambiar la pregunta  o sera marcada cerrada como "no esta claro lo que se pregunta"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era que estaba utilizando la librería PHPMailer para enviar el HTML por correo y no estaba especificando que el mail como tal tuviera "UTF-8". Añadir esta línea en el php de envío lo solucionó:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```